# Can I perform a Percentile after a composit in a single query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

My data is a series of document each with a time and a transaction id. Multiple documents can have the same transaction ID. I want to group the data by transaction id, from each group select the largest time and then use those times as input to a percentile function. I am new to elastic search and have started with the SQL-like syntax for familiarity. I can get the list of times like this

```
"query": "select time from (SELECT max("time") as time, count(*) as count, "transactionId" FROM "test-logs" group by transactionId) where count > 1)"
```

However when I try to calculate a percentile on that data like this

```
"query": "select percentile(time, 50) from (SELECT max("time") as time, count(*) as count, "transactionId" FROM "test-logs" group by transactionId) where count > 1)"
```

I get the error "Nested aggregations in sub-selects are not supported."
So I tried running the above working query through the translate function to get it into the DSL format, which is like this

```
GET /test-logs/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "_source" : false,
  "aggregations" : {
    "groupby" : {
      "composite" : {
        "size" : 1000,
        "sources" : [
          {
            "d9ea5aab" : {
              "terms" : {
                "field" : "transactionId.keyword",
                "missing_bucket" : true,
                "order" : "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "56a492fa" : {
          "max" : {
            "field" : "time"
          }
        },
        "having.2bd8ae84" : {
          "bucket_selector" : {
            "buckets_path" : {
              "a0" : "_count"
            },
            "script" : {
              "source" : "InternalQlScriptUtils.nullSafeFilter(InternalQlScriptUtils.gt(params.a0,params.v0))",
              "lang" : "painless",
              "params" : {
                "v0" : 1
              }
            },
            "gap_policy" : "skip"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results look like this

```
...
  "aggregations" : {
    "groupby" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "d9ea5aab" : "413617991"
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "d9ea5aab" : "0062a5ae-a633-453e-aff8-1130dfcbd0c7"
          },
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "56a492fa" : {
            "value" : 156.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "d9ea5aab" : "03542f13-53e0-4d58-b531-5345d133df49"
          },
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "56a492fa" : {
            "value" : 313.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "d9ea5aab" : "065d0a43-4a01-4b00-ac36-b2f08b7f1111"
          },
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "56a492fa" : {
            "value" : 393.0
          }
        }, ... etc etc
```

I want to calculate a percentile on all values in the sections marked '56a492fa'

```
"56a492fa" : {
 "value" : 313.0
}
```

Is it possible to do this in one query? If it's not possible to do in one query what is the best way to achieve the desired result?